# How to perform a function for every row in a mysql array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

UPDATE: I solved it using a for loop:

```
for ($i=0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); $i++) { 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['name'];
}
```

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

This looks kinda stupid. I'm sure im missing something that's very simple, since I was able to accomplish this before. Anyways, I want to echo some text for every item in an array. This array is derived from mySQL.

here's the code

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files"))) {
echo $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: check this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Comment: Your current code will make a fresh database query on every iteration of the loop.  You should make the call to `mysql_query()` before entering the loop, and assign the result to a variable on which you call `mysql_fetch_assoc()` within the loop.

Comment: Also, as stated in [the introduction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) to the PHP manual chapter on the `mysql_*` functions: *This extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.*

Comment: Hey, I think you're right! That's explains exactly why the page would never load, but i could see the page loading spinner spin indefinitely. Thanks! :P :D

Comment: Please have a look on my answer below. The way you are solving this seems pretty odd.

Answer (score 1):

can you post the complete code? I think you forgot the database connection.

Try this:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files") or die (mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        var_dump($row['name']);
    }
```

This will throw an error, I guess you made a mistake over there. Also, var_dump() your $row in the while to make 100% sure you have "a" value.

Also, are you sure the row does exist? If don't have any records, the echo on your $row will not work sinc it does not exist.

Also, set error reporting to E_ALL like so.

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Also, since you are running your query inside the while() loop, it will continue to run forever. So first run the query, and put it in a variable, and then loop through the results. (see my piece of code above)

Comment: Hey, it was much easier than this actually. Even if I still had to use a while loop, what eggyal commented was right.   I should run the query first, and save it to a variable, and then, in the while loop, use the mysql_array_function. That was the only mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute query individual instead of while loop because if your query return more than 1 rows it will goes under the loop. show your loop print only first data of result and your loop is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems so simple, try this way it's working.

```
    $sql="SELECT name From files";
    $names = $db->query($sql);
    while($name1 = $db->fetchByAssoc($names))
    {
        echo $name1['name'];
    }
```